# Get values from then function into variable to send it in an action

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

im trying to pass a my models service data to my action so i can change the state of all the models in the list, but im not able to pass the value of it to a variable so i can return it in my _getModelsFromBd function to pass it to my action here is the code:

this is my _getModelsFromBd code:

```
private _getModelsFromBd(): Modelo[] {
var res2;
this._modelsService.getModels().then(res => {
  res2 = res;
  console.log('res2 value inside then: ', res2);
});
console.log('res2 value outside then: ', res2)
return res2;  }
```

and this is where i pass the value to my action:

```
 @Effect()
getModelos$ = this._actions$.pipe(
ofType<GetModelos>(EModeloActions.GetModelos),
map(action => action.type),
withLatestFrom(this._modelsService.getModels()),
switchMap(async ([code, models]) => {
  console.log("value of function: ",this._getModelsFromBd());
  return of(new GetModelosSuccess(this._getModelsFromBd()));
}));
```

this is the output i get

res2 value outside then:  undefined

value of function:  undefined

res2 value inside then:  (16) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Thank you for your time

Comment: is there any reason you are returning a promise in this._modelsService.getModels()? why not observable?

Comment: @SiddharthPal im not being able to use observables to get data out of my local database, my current code is: 
`public async getModels(): Promise<Modelo[]> {
    try {
      return (await IdbHelper.idbCon.select({
        from: 'Modelos',
      })) as Modelo[];
    } catch (error) {
      throw error.message;
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are calling idbHelper which is returning a promise in `getModels` method. So first I would convert that to an observable by the following code:

```
  import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
  public getModels(): Observable<Modelo[]> {
    try {
      return from(IdbHelper.idbCon.select({ from: 'Modelos' })) as Observable<Modelo[]>;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error.message;
    }
  }
```

This would help me in converting from one(action) stream to another
and in `@Effect` I would pass it as an observable only as below

```
  @Effect()
  getModelos$ = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<GetModelos>(EModeloActions.GetModelos),
    map(action => action.type),
    switchMap(() => {
      return this._modelsService.getModels()
        .pipe(map(modelos => new GetModelosSuccess(modelos)));
    })
  );
```